# Loading assets in libgdx (clojure)

Tags: clojure, libgdx

I'm trying to make a game using clojure and libgdx. The information at [Using Libgdx with Clojure](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Using-libgdx-with-Clojure) was immensely helpful but now I'm stuck on the simple step of displaying a sprite. In my screen I have this

```
(def main-screen
  (let [stage (atom nil)]
    (proxy [Screen] []
      (show []
        (reset! stage (Stage.))
        (let [style (Label$LabelStyle. (BitmapFont.) (Color. 0 1 1 1))
              label (Label. "Hello world!" style)]
          (.addActor @stage label)))
      (render [delta]
        (.glClearColor (Gdx/gl) 0 1 0 1)
        (.glClear (Gdx/gl) GL20/GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        (doto (SpriteBatch.)
          (. begin)
          (. draw (ship-texture) 10 10)
          (. end))
        (doto @stage
          (.act delta)
          (.draw)))
      (dispose[])
      (hide [])
      (pause [])
      (resize [w h])
      (resume []))))
```

and that references a simple function above

```
(defn ship-texture [] (Texture. (.internal Gdx/files "AShip.PNG")))
```

But no matter where I put the file libgdx can't seem to find it. I've placed it in resources, src, assets and the base directory. I feel like I must be misssing something tremendously simple.

Comment: its on Assets. Also try all lowercase "aship.png", I remember reading somewhere caps cause problems. Also check the Desktop project is correctly linked to the Assets folder.

Comment: I've read something about this linking but I don't understand what that involves. Do I need to add something to the project.clj?

Comment: try this once `.internal Gdx/files "data/aship.png"` when the png file is saved in assets of the android project folder...

Comment: I don't actually have an android project folder currently. Is that absolutely needed? I'm not sure I even want to support android for my game.

Comment: This is embarrassing. It appears that the problem was that the file was corrupted or damaged somehow. Not sure how that happened but I was able to get it to work with a valid file. Is there any way to close a question?

Comment: I just flagged the question to be closed... we shall see what happens :)